# what is the REST API query for http://review.xx.yy.com/gerrit/#/c/240262/

Tags: gerrit

Can some one explain what is the exact query for the below in GERRIT REST API to get all the information

http://review.xx.yy.com/gerrit/#/c/2401262/

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following command to get all information about 2401262 change:

```
curl --user USER:PASS --request GET  http://review.xx.yy.com/a/changes/2401262
```